# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String

Tags: java, apache

I am trying a encrypt a plain text using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64. When I call the method `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(aByteArray)`, it gives the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String([B)Ljava/lang/String;
```

I am using the jar, org-apache-commons-codec.jar. Please help me as I can't understand What is wrong with this.

Comment: Check the API for the relavent version, whether it's has this method with a parameter

Answer (score 1):

First of all [encoding is not encryption](http://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding_encryption_hashing/). You are only changing representation of your string while encoding, it is easily [changed back](https://www.base64decode.org/).

Since you are getting this exception this means that you at least have this jar in your classpath. Open this jar with a suitable zip tool like 7-zip and look at your [Manifest.mf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) file. Your jar version should be greater than 1.4 according to [Base64javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html). Download latest version and replace your older version.

Comment: According to [Base64#encodeBase64String javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String(byte[])), version should be >= 1.4

Comment: @Tobías thanks, I looked at class version, not method version